# functions in separate <script src="functions.js"> tag, throws null errors on lines that interact with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been making a game, and the main js file got a little unwieldy, so I decided to put some of the longer functions in another .js file.

At first, I tried just putting the prototype declarations in this file. But it said it couldn't find the constructors to attach the prototype functions to.

So I just let them be normal functions in that new js file, and set the prototype declarations in main.js to the names of these functions in the new functions.js file

But now, before anything at runtime, it gives an error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

And it gives a similar error for the other function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null
```

Which error I get depends on which prototype declaration I put first in the main.js file. They are both throwing these errors from the function.js file on lines where it tries to do something with the DOM, like append an element, or get the width of the canvas with a certain id.

Please help!

Okay - moved the  tags into the bottom of the . It is no longer giving the null errors related to the dom, but when I try to call these functions through the prototype for the scene, it throws an error that it isn't a function. So I have

```
CrashLandingScene.prototype.draw = drawCrash();
CrashLandingScene.prototype.draw2 = drawCrash2();
```

With the drawCrash() and drawCrash2() in the other file, which is now in a script tag along with main.js in the bottom of the body of the HTML. And it is above , so the problem isn't that its called before defined.

ANSWERED - 
It turns out that you can't just put a bare function into a prototype. 
It has to go like

```
CrashLandingScene.prototype.draw = function(){
    drawCrash();
};
```

Now it works as desired.

Comment: The code would help us help you a bit more

Comment: Make sure the DOM is completely loaded before you start looking for elements and appending thigs.

Comment: Okay - did that, and have a new problem. It is no longer giving the null errors related to the dom, but when I try to call these functions through the prototype for the scene, it throws an error that it isn't a function.

So I have 

`CrashLandingScene.prototype.draw = drawCrash();
    CrashLandingScene.prototype.draw2 = drawCrash2();`

With the drawCrash() and drawCrash2(); in the other file, which is now in a script tag along with main.js in the bottom of the body of the HTML

Comment: Also the script tags are ordered correctly
 `<script src="drawingfuncts.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>`